# Change the created date attribute on a file in a zip archive using PHP

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

Is it possible to use the ZipArchive class in PHP to change the created date or modified date of a file inside of a zip file without writing the file to a disk and using touch on it and then adding the file to the zip again

Comment: Well, take a look at the documentation and see if there is such a function, I'd say.

Comment: A workaround might be to mount the zip archive to the filesystem, so that its content can be accessed in a transparent manner. That way you could use normal file operations without actually unpacking/repacking the archive. I never tried that myself, but it should work. You have to rely on the ability of your environment to do that, though.

Comment: I had a look at the docs, the only thing I saw was setExternalAttributesIndex or setExternalAttributesName but the documentation on them was pretty poor

Comment: and the workaround sounds like a massive pain and might end up being worse then just unpacking the files and using touch and readding them.

Comment: Might be, that is the nature of a workaround. Depends on various factor, for example on the size of the files.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. The external attributes have nothing to do with the file modified time, which is stored before the external attributes. I've looked at all the compression libraries in PHP, and this is not possible. I would recommend using JSON instead, if your purpose is to simply pack the data into one file and ease-of-use isn't as much of a concern as preservation of the file attributes.

I'm not sure if any software supports setting the file modified time, so you would have to alter the source code to support such a thing or code it yourself. I had a look at the bzip source code (NOT the PHP extension), and it simply copies this from the source file. Furthermore, the default file modified time is stored in DOS format, which is only accurate to the nearest 2 seconds, so you would have to store the proper file modified time in an extra field. PHP does not support writing to or reading extra fields.

The simplest solution would be using your filesystem.

Sources:
Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29
Basic description: http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/ZIP
Reverse engineering: http://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/templates/files/ZIPTemplate.bt
Bzip: http://www.bzip.org/
PHP comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.statindex.php#118629