# ZipArchive ignores date_default_timezone_set for files placed in the .zip file

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I'm running PHP `7.0.33` on a Linux server (shared web hosting).

With [`date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');`](https://www.php.net/date_default_timezone_set) I can properly set my timezone.

`echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` shows the correct date-time.

But the files added in a `.zip` with [`ZipArchive`](https://www.php.net/ZipArchive) obtain the server date-time.

The files' sources are created on the fly.

Here is the code I use to zip the files:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($pathZip, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach($fileList as $fileName => $fileContents)
{
    $zip->addFromString($fileName, $fileContents);
}
$zip->close();
// Note: I removed all try-catch and false returns checks to simplify the code
```

How to add files in the `.zip` maintaining the timezone set with `date_default_timezone_set`, possibly using `ZipArchive`?

I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365627/change-the-created-date-attribute-on-a-file-in-a-zip-archive-using-php) post, but it's quite old.

Comment: Perhaps you should confirm that the server has its date/time and timezone set correctly. I've seen numerous shared-host-badmins that leave the OS-configured timezone as one thing, and then manually set the clock to match a completely different timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Storing the filedate inside the zip will always use the filesystem date, since there is no function to alter the file date when adding the file, you can [touch()](https://www.php.net/touch) the file before adding it.

Timezone settings are only for displaying the time, setting the timezone does not affect the timestamp.

```
$date1   = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$date2   = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome'));
echo $date1->getTimestamp() . PHP_EOL;
echo $date2->getTimestamp() . PHP_EOL;
```

Result:

```
1569568587
1569568587
```

You can get the offset of the timezone and change the time.

```
$offset = $date2->getOffset();
$newTime = $date2->getTimestamp() + $offset;
$res = touch($fileName, $newTime);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I create the files on the fly, so can I use `touch()` or something similar without save it on disk?

Comment: There's no way to do it without saving the file, maybe you could use another compression library that supports editing the file's timestamp, if there is any.

Comment: Maybe `rar` can do that, I have it installed on the web hosting.

Comment: [getfiletime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/rarentry.getfiletime.php)
Again, you can only read the file's time :(

Comment: I think the best solution will be to touch the uploaded files with the new time adding the $offset

Answer (score 1):

`ZipArchive` doesnt support this feature.

I suggest you use simple wrapper for work with zips - [ZipStream-PHP](https://github.com/maennchen/ZipStream-PHP)

Basic use case for you looks like this:

```
$resultArchive = fopen($pathZip, 'w');

$options = new ZipStream\Option\Archive();
$options->setSendHttpHeaders(false);
$options->setOutputStream($resultArchive);

$zip = new ZipStream\ZipStream('example.zip', $options);

foreach($fileList as $fileName => $fileContents)
{
    $fileOptions = new ZipStream\Option\File();
    $fileOptions->setTime(new \DateTime()); // set your custom date, by default is NOW
    $zip->addFile($fileName, $fileContents, $fileOptions);
}

$zip->finish();

fclose($resultArchive);
```

Comment: @Gasol, some details?

Comment: Ok, I got it. The last modified time of file has changed, https://asciinema.org/a/NaMs7gUiCFOlEh299JC2vOoT7 Check it out.

Answer (score -1):

File uploaded time is related to server time.
So, you can do a trick to do that.
e.g. Store file upload time on db (upload_time, upload_my_time)

Comment: My question is not related to upload file. Anyway, for uploaded files is sinple to store the real datetime in the db cause of it get be obtained with setted timezone